# User input for gender not functioning

Tags: python, if-statement, variables, input, user-input

I am attempting to make a game that I made via Rpg Maker MV in python but I've hit a road block in the if statement or rather the gender input. The code is meant to have the user input either "Boy" or "Girl" and depending on that the variable "gender" will be set for pronouns. How ever the console is saying [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/puXba.png)

This is the code

```
 import time
    print ("Elvoria")
    print ("Start")
    input = input()
    if input == ("Start"):
      print ("Always Great To See New People")
      time.sleep(1)
      print ("Now Are You A Boy Or Girl")
      genderin = input()
    if input == ("Boy"):
      gender = 1
    elif input == ("Girl"):
      gender = 2
    else:
      print ("Error")
```

Comment: Please always include error messages as text, not images. Note that `input = input()` just gave the name `input` to the string the user entered, and that it doesn't refer to the function anymore, so you can't use that function later in your code. Use a different variable name, and more generally don't use names of builtin functions as variable names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check the input using the variable name `genderin` that you defined, instead of `input == ("Boy")`.
EDIT: Also, you are mirroring the built-in method `input()` with the variable name `input` and you should not do that. Rename your variable to e.g. `start_input`.

```
import time
print ("Elvoria")
print ("Start")
start_input = input()
if start_input == "Start":
  print ("Always Great To See New People")
  time.sleep(1)
  print ("Now Are You A Boy Or Girl")
  genderin = input()
if genderin == "Boy":
  gender = 1
elif genderin == "Girl":
  gender = 2
else:
  print ("Error")
```

Comment: @ThierryLathuille I tested it just after posting and edited the original answer. I thought the only error was the if condition, so I wasn't aware of the built-in override at first.

Answer (score 0):

You're defining the variable "`input`" on line 4 to be a string, given from the "`input`" function. This overrides the keyword. Then, on line 9, you're calling "`input`" again. Since you've replaced the built-in function with a string, an error is thrown (the error "not callable" means that you're trying to treat a non-function like a function).

Here's your code sample, without overriding built-in methods:

```
import time
print ("Elvoria")
print ("Start")
user_input = input()
if user_input == ("Start"):
  print ("Always Great To See New People")
  time.sleep(1)
  print ("Now Are You A Boy Or Girl")
  genderin = input()
if genderin == ("Boy"):
  gender = 1
elif genderin == ("Girl"):
  gender = 2
else:
  print ("Error")
```

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid using `input` as a varible name, since a built-in function with that name already exists, `input()`. So just change it's name to something else. Secondly, you're storing the gender input (boy/girl) in `genderin`, but then checking `input`, when you should be checking `genderin`. So the code after fixing these would look something like this:

```py
import time
print ("Elvoria")
print ("Start")
choice = input()
if choice == "Start":
    print("Always Great To See New People")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Now Are You A Boy Or Girl?")
    genderin = input()
if genderin == "Boy":
    gender = 1
elif genderin == "Girl":
    gender = 2
else:
    print("Error")
```

I have used `choice` for demonstration purposes, you can use a different name if you want, just remember to make sure that a python built-in with that name doesn't exist. Also, no need to put `("Start")` in the if statement, use `"Start"` instead (same goes for other if/elif statements)

You have also used `print ("example")` (space between print and brackets), i've rarely ever seen someone using this, most people use `print("example")` instead.

Finally a tip -> You can make the string lowercase, `genderin = genderin.lower()` to manage case sensitivity, i.e, both `boy` and `Boy` will be valid inputs, etc.